# Scrolling is not smooth in android Grid View

Tags: android, performance

In my android application, I am loading the images from the API's. but after the images are loaded in the Grid View, the scrolling is not smooth. I am using Asynchronous threads to fetch the images so that it does not block the UI.

Any suggestions now to improve the performance of scrolling.

Comment: Do you reuse your views and use ViewHolder pattern?

Comment: Can you add the code for your Adapter (specifically the getView() method)

Comment: I had this problem before too and I decreased the size of my images and that worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading images in separate thread definitely helps, however there's another important performance issue to take care of here, and that's "view reusability", once you've set the image in your Adapter, make sure that you are actually reusing the views provided in the getView method of the adapter, and not creating/inflating a new Layout(GridElement) every time that method is called, this is usually what causes the scrolling to go slow once all the images have been loaded, there's several patterns available to approach this issue, you should read about ViewHolder, is the most common and easy to use pattern for this issue...

Hope this Helps...

Regards

Comment: Now, the scrolling is fine but the image is changing positions on scrolling down. I am passing the imageView object to set the image after its downloaded. I used ViewHolder for saving the ImageView, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Code for getView() method
{{{

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(position);
                imageURL = song.get(VariablesList.TAG_ALBUM_IMAGE);
                View v = null;
                if (convertView != null)
                        v = convertView;
                else
                        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlayout_item, parent, false);
                final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
                final Thread startAlbum = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {

                                imageView.setImageBitmap(AlbumList
                                                .LoadImagetoGridView(imageURL));

                                synchronized (this) {
                                        this.notifyAll();
                                }
                        }
                };

                synchronized (startAlbum) {
                        startAlbum.start();
                        try {
                                startAlbum.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        // @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                albumUrl = new StringBuffer(resources.getString(R.string.songsListURL));
                                String albumIndex = song.get("id");
                                albumName = (song.get("name"));
                                imageURL = song.get(VariablesList.TAG_ALBUM_IMAGE);
                                SongsList albumList = new SongsList(imageURL, albumUrl,
                                                albumName,albumIndex,resources);
                                Thread threadAlbumList = new Thread(albumList);
                                threadAlbumList.start();

                                synchronized (albumList) {
                                        try {
                                                albumList.wait();
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }
                                if (!NewMediaPlayer.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                        HashMap<String, String> playingSong = NewMediaPlayer.selectedSongs
                                                        .get(0);
                                        if (playingSong != null) {
                                                String url = playingSong.get("songUrl");
                                                String songName = playingSong.get("songName");
                                                if (songName != null)
                                                        {
                                                         NewMediaPlayer.songTitleLabel.setText(albumName
                                                                        + " - " + songName);
                                                         NewMediaPlayer.songTitle.setText(albumName+"-"+songName);
                                                        }
                                                NewMediaPlayer.playSong(url);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                });

                TextView itemAlbumName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
                itemAlbumName.setText(song.get("name"));
                itemAlbumName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(position);
                                String songIndex = song.get("id");
                                String albumName = (song.get("name"));
                                Intent in = new Intent(context, SongListActivity.class);
                                in.putExtra("albumIndex", songIndex);
                                in.putExtra("albumName", albumName);
                                in.putExtra("AlbumImage", song.get(VariablesList.TAG_ALBUM_IMAGE));
                                context.startActivity(in);
                        }
                });

                return v;
        }

}}}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing the setImageBitmap in a separate thread when you are forcing the main UI Thread to wait, anyway?

Comment: how to load the Bitmap image on the UI then?

Comment: To do it just on a separate thread, is pretty much what your doing, but without calling for wait, because that's practically loading it on main thread since you are waiting for it to load anyway, the best way is to let the thread run on its own, and once done, THEN you set the image, BUT you must do using handler since, in order to modify views you need the code to execute in the main thread. Now if you are downloading imgs from URL take a look on the volley project, it has a caching images mechanism that works perfect, so if an image has been already downloaded it just get it from cache...

Comment: @Martin, I got the issue, I need to remove the wait on the thread for loading the image from URL as it is causing the scrolling to slow down. So, instead of waiting, I can shift it to asynchronous thread as I cannot fetch the image from http on main thread. Any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking efforts Use Universal Image loader library.And its performance is good.
In onCreate method 
  gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,ImagesArrayPath));

```
    private static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private  final String[] IMAGE_URLS ;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    ImageAdapter(Context context,String source[]) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        IMAGE_URLS=source;

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.ico_place_holder)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGE_URLS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                    }
                });

        return view;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

May this will help you. Enjoy Coding.